# Getting Error "Value Cannot Be NULL" when running a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am running this LINQ to Entities query below, it crashes with error saying `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: outer"}`

```
    foreach (ProviderAddresses pa in providerAddresseses)
    {
        var eaAddrs = (from addrs in this.Context.EaAddresseses
            join ea in this.Context.EntityAssignments
                on addrs.Ea_K equals ea.Ea_K
            where addrs.ProviderAddress_K == pa.ProviderAddress_K
            select new
            {
                EAAddress = addrs,
                AssignmentRTK = ea.Assignment_RTK
            });
```

But the parameter I am passing is NOT really null, so what is causing this? Is it because I am passing a List object and joining with real tables in LINQ to Entities? and they don't work together?

Comment: whats the exact exception?

Comment: @Pseudonym : That was the exact exception.

Comment: `outer` refers to the outer table in your join; in this case, it's `this.Context.EaAddresseses`. Either `Context` or `EaAddresseses` is `null` here, most likely the latter.

Comment: Yes you are right @Cᴏʀʏ , this.Context.EaAddresseses is null for some reason. Thanks.